# CSS center, fixed nav

Tags: css

I have a page that is 1600px wide. The main area though is only 900px wide. I have a navigation that is suppose to be fixed in the center of the page ( which it is ). My problem is when I open the page, the page is fixed left instead of being centered when opened. What do I need to do to center everything within the 900px when a user visits the site?

The code isn't exact because it's detailed but it basically goes like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wznQk/

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="subheader">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li>HOME</li>
                        <li>ABOUT</li>
                        <li class="logo"><img src="images/ogsystemslogo.png" /></li>
                        <li>CAREERS</li>
                        <li>CONTACT</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                    <div class="undernav">
                        <div class="short">
                            <img src="images/bluemark.png" />
                            <div class="top">TOP OGS NEWS:</div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.body {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}

.subheader {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0px;
}

.navigation {
    font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    border: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #006699;
    background-color: white;
}

    .navigation ul {
        width: 590px;
        height: 20px;
        list-style: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 55px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;

    }

    .navigation ul li {
        width: 70px;
        height: 15px;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 35px;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

Comment: What is this for `margin-left: 0 auto;` ? Do you want it to `margin:0 auto;` ?

Comment: I fixed that margin-left, just an error. @loops I'm not sure if what you have is right. What did you change so I can see if it works?

Comment: @Keith http://jsfiddle.net/ZdqCe/

Comment: it moved it over slightly but it still isn't showing up directly in the center when the page opens. The page still starts heavy left and then hits the navigation halfway into the page.

Comment: did you mean to give your `<body>` a class of `.body` ? if not, you need to remove the `.`

Comment: no I missed that thanks, but still didn't center everything.

Comment: @Keith this works fine for me. http://jsbin.com/eVUn/1

Comment: Let me mess with that and see if I can get this to work in mine thanks!

Comment: if you add in a height instead of %, you can see the scrollbar at the bottom be all the way to the left. What I'd like is for that bar to be in the middle with the content in the middle.

Comment: just use body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

Comment: I shrunk down the size from 1600px to 1300px and it is more in the middle, but I have a background image that you can clearly see that the image starts left and then ends on the right showing white space. It is like the border left is attached to the page so when you click on the left size to resize in and out, it pushes everything right instead of having equal white space on the left and right of the image to start.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this CSS instead of yours. In your CSS I found lot of unwanted CSS tags but I keep them as it is.

```
body {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
.subheader {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0px;
}
.navigation {
    font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 590px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #006699;
    background-color: white;
}
.navigation ul {
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 55px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
.navigation ul li {
    width: 70px;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 35px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
.header {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -800px;/*half of your total width*/
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Added `left: 50%;` `margin-left: -800px;/*half of your total width*/` to your .header class

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/avinvarghese/wznQk/3/show/